# Header contents of a .bin file in Linux

Tags: linux, header, binary

Which contents have the header of an executable .bin file in Linux?

I found information for .exe files in Windows but I can't find any information for .bin files.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, in Linux, executable files may be called "binary" but don't have an explicit ".bin"

Linux generally uses the ELF format.  The first byte is 0x7F followed by ascii for E, L, F  - this is easily visible if you can load the binary into a text editor or print it at the command line using 'cat' or 'less'.   After that... well I'm rusty but details are easily found on the web.

Try http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/elf-object-file-format/  and http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/elf.html for a starter.  (I found these with a superficial quick search, and do not claim these are the best.  Happy hunting!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking. But most Linux executables use the **ELF** format.

The [readelf utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) can read metadata from ELF executables.

[ELF on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)